# What is the proper way to define instance variables in Backbone models?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm wondering how I should define instance variables inside a Backbone Model. This is the way I'm currently doing it:

```
class GeneSet extends Backbone.Model
    initialize: (parsedGenes)->
        @set parsedGenes: parsedGenes
        @set geneNames: (gene.gene_name for gene in @get("parsedGenes"))
        @set geneIds: ("gene_#{id}" for id in [1..@get("parsedGenes").length])
        @set columnNames: @getColumnNames()
        @set columnGroups: @getColumnGroups()
        @set geneExpressions: @getGeneExpressions()
        @set groupedGeneExpressions: @getGroupedGeneExpressions()
        @set extent: @getExtent()

    clusterColor: ->
        d3.scale.category20()()

    getGeneNameById: (geneId)->
        @get("geneNames")[@get("geneIds").indexOf(geneId)]

    getColumnGroups: ->
        _.uniq((@get("columnNames")).map((columnName)->
            columnName.split("_")[0]
        ))

    getExtent: ->
        expressions = _.flatten(@get("geneExpressions").map (geneExpression)->
            geneExpression.map (item)->
                item.y
        )
        d3.extent(expressions)

    getColumnNames: ->
        Object.keys(@get("parsedGenes")[0]).filter (columnName) ->
            !columnName.match(/cluster/) && isNumber(parsedGenes[1][columnName])


    getGeneExpressions: ->
        @get("parsedGenes").map (gene) =>
            @get("columnNames").map (columnName) -> 
                x: columnName
                y: +gene[columnName] # make numeric
```

This seems a little redundant to do `@set columnGroups: @getColumnGroups()` and having to get every variable using `@get("...")` seems kind of verbose (I wish I could do `@variableName`). My question is, is this the right way of using models and instance variables or am I doing it wrong? Also, is there any difference to doing this?:

```
    class GeneSet extends Backbone.Model
        initialize: (parsedGenes)->
            @parsedGenes = parsedGenes
            @geneNames = (gene.gene_name for gene in @parsedGenes)
            @geneIds = ("gene_#{id}" for id in [1..@parsedGenes.length])
            @clusters = (gene.cluster for gene in @parsedGenes)
            @descriptions = (gene.description for gene in @parsedGenes)
            @columnNames = @getColumnNames()
            @columnGroups = @getColumnGroups()
            @geneExpressions = @getGeneExpressions()
            @groupedGeneExpressions = @getGroupedGeneExpressions()
            @extent = @getExtent()
```

And then, from the view just doing `@model.columnNames`

Comment: how do you observe attribute changes if you do the second way ? if descriptions changes you cant observe description. the only alternative is to use ES5 Object.defineProperty but verbose and not compatible with older browsers . furthermore it doesnt fit the backbone "way" that well.

Comment: I see, somebody did it here: http://srackham.wordpress.com/2011/10/16/getters-and-setters-for-backbone-model-attributes/

Comment: i did not say you cant , i said if you have like 20 props ... well i guess you could create a helper function .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I do in my base model superclass. It's pretty much against the backbone design, but I too hate using `get` and `set` and I want real methods behind all attribute access. So I do some metaprogramming and generate named get/set methods. So instead of having to do:

```
model.get("name")
model.set("name", "Tom")
```

I can just do

```
model.name()
model.name("Tom")
```

Here's my base code to do this automatically for any arbitrary `attributes` object.

```
addConvenienceMethods = ->
  for prop, value of this.attributes
    ((prop) ->
      #Define a setter/getter function
      this[prop] = (newValue...) ->
        if newValue.length
          obj = {}
          obj[prop] = newValue[0]
          this.set obj
          return this
        else
          return this.get prop
      #Use the newly-defined setter function to store the default value
      this[prop](value)
    ).call(this, prop)

########## Base Model Superclass ##########
class exports.Model extends Backbone.Model
  initialize: ->
    addConvenienceMethods.call this
```

Note this was written on a backbone version old enough to not support `set("key", "value")`. If I were to update it, I'd probably use that variant. Note since the `set` flavor returns the object, they are chainable: `model.name("John").email("john@example.com").role("admin")`